# Unittesting a function that gets value from excel

Tags: python, pytest

I'm new to python and have written a few basic test in Pytest. I have a function that gets and returns two values from an excel sheet.

```
def function(g):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("name_of_execel.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=3, max_col=3): 
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == g:
                first_value = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=6).value
                second_value = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=7).value
    return first_value, second_value
```

Now I need to pytest this function and I don't know if pytest can access excel to get values to test them. Do I need to write a function in test_project that gets all values from excel so it can use them for testing?

I've tried asserting input but that returns UnboundLocalError:cannot access local variable because it's not associated with a value.

Comment: Please include your pytest code that raises `UnboundLocalError` for more infomation.

Comment: `from project import function

def test_function():
    assert function("karlovac") == 0.2, 0.33`

Comment: Maybe you can monkeypatch openpyxl.load_workbook to unittest your function only

Comment: Your assert should compare the function output to the tuple (0.2, 0.33). The parentheses are required for the comparison as your function returns a tuple. However, this should not lead to an UnboundLocalError.

Comment: The fact that `return first_value, second_value` can be reached without first defining either variable is a bug. `function` seems to *assume* that `name_of_execel.xlsx` will provide a cell containing `g`, which may not be the case.